# How do I know app is launched / updated in a different country

Tags: android, google-play

Basically, we have two versions of the same app. One is available in my country and the other in another (there is a huge difference between the two, so we had to do them separately).

After updating the app, I usually go sit on the Play store and ensure that it has updated (new version number and release notes), how would I know if the one in the other country has updated? (I only released it today for the first time, so don't even know if it launched successfully)

Sorry, feels like a silly question - but, I could not find a simple solution yet.

Comment: Suggestion, have you tried to implement Google Analytics?

Comment: @cod-e-rection no actually, will investigate!!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you update your app over Google play store and it is successfully up and running you will get a Notification on your Google play console with saying that your app is live.

if you dint get the notification then you need to check whats wrong with the release management.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions:

- Google Play lets you know both in the Play Console and in the [Play Copnsole App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.playconsole) that your publication has gone live
- In the Play console app and the Play console you can see install statistics, so you can see if anyone is installing
- You could always use a VPN to check to appear if you are coming from another country
- If you have access to a credit card from the other country you could create a second Google Account and use that credit card as a payment method to buy an in-app product. Google Play usually bases the user's country on where the payment method is if they can
- You can use [Firebase analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) to measure things like installs of the other version